# How to get an integer representation of a string

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to get an integer representation the first bytes of a string in PHP. I don't want to parse any number in the string, I actually want to use first bytes of the string as integer without any conversion. How can I do that?

For reference, here is what I'm trying to achieve, but in C:

```
char *str = "Hello World";
printf("%d", *(int *) str); // prints 1819043144 (machine dependent)
```

Comment: In C you're also converting string into an int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [unpack()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) - With `I` [unsigned integer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php#refsect1-function.pack-parameters) (machine dependent size and byte order):

```
// 1819043144
echo unpack('I*', 'Hello World')[1];
```